# Can I schedule a one time job or does it have to be recurring?

Tags: scheduled-apex

Is there always a need to do the kill cron job after scheduling it?

Instead can I just schedule a one time job?

If so, what is the difference in syntax between a recurring job and a one time job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule a job with a specific set cron string, e.g. `0 0 0 21 MAY ? 2022` to run something exactly at midnight tonight (at the time of this answer). After the job runs, it will be flagged as Completed and will not run again nor count against the 100 scheduled jobs governor limit. It is otherwise identical to a recurring job, but will contain no wildcards except for "day of week", which will be set to "?" ("do not care"). If you want to schedule a one-off batch job, you can also use `System.scheduleBatch`, which schedules a batch job to run after a specified number of minutes, and never again.

Comment: When you say "otherwise identical", what do you mean? What are the differences between the syntax for the recurring job and the one-time job?

Comment: A word of warning for close-in scheduling of one-off jobs; see [this posting](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdesgUAB/scheduling-a-job-in-the-near-future-is-not-guaranteed-to-work).

Comment: The difference in syntax for a one-off job is that you do not use wildcards in the date/time specification.